# SSIS keyboard shortcuts for packages layout

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2019

I am making a few edits on huge DTSX packages in Visual Studio (SSIS), and my target is to make a more tidy layout of the flows.
For this reason, I use to select part of the flows and then use the following menu:

- `Format` > `Auto Layout` > `Diagram`
- `Format` > `Align` > `Center`
- `Format` > `Make Same Size` > `Both`
- `Format` > `Horizontal Spacing` > `Make Equal`
- `Format` > `Vertical Spacing` > `Make Equal`

Is there a key shortcut for these commands?
I looked over Google and the official Microsoft documentation, but I didn't find anything helpful in this direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, there are no default keyboard shortcuts assigned for the layout commands:

[image]

**You can assign your own shortcuts!**

In the top menu strip, go to *Tools > Options*.

[image]

Once the options dialog is shown, click on the keyboard section. And select the command you are looking to assign the shortcuts. In the "Show commands containing", type `Format.` to find the commands related to formatting, e.g. `Format.Diagram`, `Format.MakeHorizontalSpacingEqual`, etc. Then press the shortcut you want and click on the assign button *(as shown below)*.

[image]

After assigning the shortcuts, you check the command you selected in the menu strip and note that the keyboard shortcut is shown beside it.

[image]